# Eloquent Query Builder in laravel 5

Tags: php, sql, eloquent

How can i change this sql statement to Eloquent query ..

```
SELECT * FROM `promotions` 
WHERE 
(CURDATE() 
BETWEEN from_date - INTERVAL 2 DAY AND from_date) 
OR 
(CURDATE() >= from_date AND CURDATE() <= to_date)
```

I tried like that >>

```
$start =  date("Y-m-d 00:00:00"); //todate
$end =    // todate + 2
return $this->model->whereBetween('from_date',[$start,$end])->get();
```

but i don't know how to change this section >>

```
OR (CURDATE() >= from_date AND CURDATE() <= to_date)
```

Please show me the right way .. Thanks and respect to all .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should do the job:

```
$today = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$end_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+2 days'));
$this->model->whereBetween('from_date',[$today,$end_date])
            ->orWhere( function( $query ) {
                 $query->where($today, '>=', 'from_date')
                       ->where($today, '<=', 'to_date');
            })
            ->get();
```